# Django Update Model Field with Variable User Input... .update(key=value)

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models

I'm attempting to create a function to allow updates to fields based on the front-end input.

The handler would receive a `profile_updates` dictionary with two keys. Each will contain a list of key/value pairs.

`list_of_updates['custom_permissions'] = [{"is_staff":"True"},{"other_permission":"False"}]`

```
def update_profile(message):
    list_of_updates = message['profile_updates']
    user_update_id = message['user_id']

    for update in list_of_updates['custom_permissions']:
        for key, value in update.iteritems():
            User.objects.filter(id=user_update_id).update(key=value)
```

I would like to make 'key' a variable fed from the .iteritems().

Appreciate anyone's input on how, or if, this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to loop through the dict. You can pass it as a kwarg expansion.

```
def update_profile(message):
    list_of_updates = message['profile_updates']
    user_update_id = message['user_id']

    for update in list_of_updates['custom_permissions']:
        User.objects.filter(id=user_update_id).update(**update)
```

Comment: Seems to be somewhat working. Trying to adjust a boolean value in a separate table as well and it doesn't seem to be update, but it's not throwing any errors.

I've tried "0" and "False"...

```socket.send(JSON.stringify({
                    "command": "update_profile",
                    "user_id": "1",
                    "profile_updates": {"custom_permissions":[{"can_chat":"0"},]}
                }))```

Comment: I think you should either send an integer or a boolean.

Comment: Yeah, I found it. Not a Javascript dev. Have to make a variable first and pass the variable into the JSON.stringify()

```var test = {
        "command": "update_profile",
        "user_id": "1",
        "profile_updates": {
                "custom_permissions":[{"can_chat":false}]}
    }

socket.send(JSON.stringify(test))```

Thanks!!